# MYSQL.CONNECTOR ISSUE WHILE CONNECTING MYSQL AND PYTHON

Tags: python

I am trying to connect mysql(8.0) and python(3.9.6) using mysql.connector but getting the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Windows 10

same code working for `pymysql`

the code used:

```
import mysql.connector as sql 
s=sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='<correct password>')
```

Have checked everything but can't solve it yet.

Comment: It should be ```password```?

Comment: Have a look at the valid arguments in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html). That aside, it's a good idea to create a user other than root for regular use.

Comment: Passwd and user are valid short forms as per documentation,but,even if i use full form,the result is the same.

Comment: I actually need to work out with root,so, i am stuck.

Comment: moreover,same code working for pymysql,where i changed only mysql.connector  with pymysql.

Comment: You need to provide the code that **doesn't work**, in your question.

Comment: Waiting for a reply to help me out of this trouble!